# Creating a Google Map based on a user selection in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I had this working fine with one location. However, I needed the user to be able to choose between one of two office locations and then generate the Google Map based on what location the user chooses. The map is initialized through a function "initMap" which takes in the content info for the info window; and the latitude and longitude for the office location.

As I said, I had this working before but now I'm getting errors, primarily around the use of the object latLng, complaining about the '.' used when initializing the marker.

```
markers[0] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {latLng.lat, latLng.lng},
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
              });
```

The primary change I made when I was moving this to a user-selected map, was change the latLng from set numbers to a variable that is determined in the onAddressChange function.

```
function onAddressChange(city) {
            if(city === 'Cockeysville'){
                contentInfo = "<div id='infoAddress'>Cockeysville, MD</div>";
                latLng = {
                    lat: 39.490837, 
                    lng: -77.438154 
                };
                initMap(contentInfo, latLng);
            } else {
                contentInfo = "<div id='infoAddress'>>Richmond, VA</div>";
                latLng = {
                    lat: 37.543268, 
                    lng: -77.581338   
                };
                initMap(contentInfo, latLng);
            }
        }
```

I'm still learning quite a bit about javascript and the Google Map API so let me know what I'm doing wrong, please! Check my fiddle, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u7r61hrw/).

Answer (score 1):

Your position object needs to have the 'lat' and 'lng' properties, like so:

```
markers[0] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
        lat: latLng.lat,
        lng: latLng.lng
    },
    map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});
```

...although, you could use your latLng object directly, like so:

```
markers[0] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});
```